# Different results between gcc and clang when compiling a rather simple c++11 program

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

I'm trying to understand whether the different behavior exposed by gcc vs. clang in the output of this simple C++11 program is due to a bug in clang (Xcode 5.0.2, OS X 10.8.5). The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {


    int matrix[][3]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    auto dyn_matrix = new int[3][3]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};

    std::cout << matrix[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << dyn_matrix[0][1] << std::endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

As shown, I'm trying to use uniform initialization to initialize an anonymous (resp. named) multidimensional array of size `3x3`. When compiling with gcc 4.7 from MacPorts the expected output is obtained:

```
$g++-mp-4.7 -std=c++11 dyn_matrix.cpp -o dyn_matrix 
$ ./dyn_matrix
2
2
$
```

Conversely, in case clang is used the output reads:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ dyn_matrix.cpp -o dyn_matrix_clang
$ ./dyn_matrix_clang 
2
4
$
```

In this case the result is (apparently) wrong. `clang --version` reports:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Who's to blame? me, gcc or clang?

**UPDATE Dec 11th, 2013:** The bug should have been fixed in r196995. Unfortunately, we still do not know how long it will take before Apple updates the version of clang that ships with Xcode.

**UPDATE Dec 9th, 2013:** I submitted a bug report on the LLVM bugzilla platform. It has indeed been recognized as a bug, a patch is currently under review, see http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20131209/095099.html.

Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 says `2 2` for another statistic.

Comment: Which version of clang++ are you using?

Comment: +1 for asking a good and interesting question. Confirmed that `clang++` v4.2 on OS X 10.7.5 also produces code outputting "2 4". My intuition says it's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'd say that `2 2` is indeed the correct result. @juanchopanza, I'll edit my question so as to report the output of `clang --version`.

Comment: Hm. The version of clang I have currently installed crashes on this code (clang version 3.4 (trunk 193991)). Time to update and see if that's better...

Comment: I've just tried with `clang 3.4 (trunk 187030)`, and I can confirm that it crashes when trying to compile that code.

Comment: What does `sizeOf` report for the variables and their elements?

Comment: Here's a more complete live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4465ae5a4677dc77 . @Dave `matrix` is a `int [3][3]` and `dyn_matrix` is a `int (*)[3]`, so `sizeof` won't help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:** Thanks to Faisal Vali and Richard Smith, this bug has been corrected in Clang ToT; see the [test file](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/CodeGenCXX/cxx11-initializer-array-new.cpp?revision=196995&view=markup&pathrev=196995) introduced by the commit.

---

According to **§8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]** it appears that Clang is wrong:

> 11/ Braces can be elided in an *initializer-list* as follows. If the *initializer-list* begins with a left brace, then the succeeding comma-separated list of *initializer-clauses* initializes the members of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more *initializer-clauses* than members. If, however, the *initializer-list* for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough *initializer-clauses* from the list are taken to initialize the members of the subaggregate; any remaining *initializer-clauses* are left to initialize the next member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate is a member. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> float y[4][3] = {
>     { 1, 3, 5 },
>     { 2, 4, 6 },
>     { 3, 5, 7 },
> };
> ```
>
> is a completely-braced initialization: 1, 3, and 5 initialize the first row of the array `y[0]`, namely `y[0][0]`, `y[0][1]`, and `y[0][2]`. Likewise the next two lines initialize `y[1]` and `y[2]`. The initializer ends early and therefore `y[3]`s elements are initialized as if explicitly initialized with an expression of the form `float()`, that is, are initialized with `0.0`. In the following example, braces in the *initializer-list* are elided; however the *initializer-list* has the same effect as the completely-braced *initializer-list* of the above example,
>
> ```
> float y[4][3] = {
>     1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7
> };
> ```
>
> The initializer for y begins with a left brace, but the one for `y[0]` does not, therefore three elements from the list are used. Likewise the next three are taken successively for `y[1]` and `y[2]`. —*end example* ]

Which I think applies because of **§5.3.4 [expr.new]**:

> 15/ A *new-expression* that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:
>
> - If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is default-initialized (**§8.5**); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
> - Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of **§8.5** for direct initialization.

Comment: +1 The last sentence in your 2nd quote basically says it. The initializers are to be interpreted the same (and since they're identical in the code snippet, the output thus must be identical too).

Comment: @Damon: I hope so, however past experience dictates that for every absolute in the Standard, there is at least one exception hidden away in an unrelated paragraph... not even counting that this applies only if `{ ... }` is indeed a *new-initializer* :/

Comment: I submitted a bug report on the LLVM bugzilla platform. It has indeed been recognized as a bug, a patch is currently under review, see http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20131209/095099.html. I'll edit the original question so as to reflect the change.

Comment: At first I didn't notice you had already reported that the bug has been fixed. Anyway, the main question has been altered to reflect the update. Thanks.